# In how many ways can we choose 3 subsets, $A$, $B$ and $C$ From set $S$ with $n$ elements so that the union is $S$.

Tags: combinatorics, combinations, combinatorial-proofs

I'm having a little trouble with this combinatorics problem even though I think I've kinda figured it out.The question asks for the number of ways to choose three subsets from set $S = \{ 1,2,3,\dots,n\}$ so that their union is $S$.
the thing is I already figured out the number of ways to do this for choosing two subsets which is :
$$ \underbrace{{n\choose n} 3 ^n}_{\text{# of unions that are equal to S}} + {n\choose n-1}3^{n-1} + {n \choose n - 2}3^{n-2} + \dots + \underbrace{{n\choose n-n} 3 ^{n-n}}_{\text{# of unions that are }\emptyset} = 4^n $$

so for choosing 2 subsets of $S$ it would have $3^n$ ways so that the union would be $S$.
but I'm trying to find out how many ways there is with 3 subsets(also it is not mentioned that they must be disjoint). And I would also much appreciate a more general way.(maybe for $k$ number of subsets).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**For $k$ subsets to have union $S$**

There are $2^k$ possible combinations of $k$ objects since each can either be included or not.

Each element has to be in at least one of the $k$ subsets and so we only need consider $2^k-1$ of the possibilities.

This applies to each of the $n$ elements of $S$ and so the required number of choices is $(2^k-1)^n$.

Answer (score 0):

HINT

The key is to understand the $2$-subset case, which you solved correctly and which had a very *suggestive* answer.  Why is the answer $3^n$?  It is because each element $x$ can be in one of three colors, uh I mean, one of three situations.  :)  Viz, $x \in A$ only, or, $x \in B$ only, or, $x \in A \cap B$.  After all, if the union $A\cup B = S$ then the only rule is that no element can be in neither $A$ nor $B$.

Now can you generalize it to $3$ subsets, and indeed $k$ subsets?

Comment: the way I came up with that answer was because I thought of it in this way:

Comment: then...  do you see the generalization to $3$ subsets?

Comment: $n  \choose n$ + ... + $ n \choose n-n$ is the number of ways we can construct a subset of S and then I figured that there would be $3^n$ ways of getting the same  union if we had two subsets.(by induction)

Comment: hmm, forget the binomial coefficients.  i'm saying $3^n$ is the answer for $2$-subsets based on a direct coloring argument: each element has choice of $3$ colors, and each choice can be independent of all others.  so for $3$-subsets, how many choices can each element have?

Comment: I guess that would be $7^n$ which is $x \in A$ only ,$x \in B$ only, $x \in C$ only, $x \in {A\cap C}$, $x \in {A\cap B}$, $x \in {B\cap C}$, $x \in {A\cap B\cap C}$ which is $7^n$ ?

Comment: yep!  but hopefully you're actually _convinced_ as opposed to just "I guess..." :)  First of all, convince yourself that $A\cup B\cup C=S$ iff every $x$ is in any of the $7$ situations.  Next convince yourself that every different color assignment changes at least one $x$'s membership status, so the sets $A,B,C$ are different.

Comment: So a better way of saying it is that if $x \in S$ then $x \in ((A - B)-C)$, $x \in ((B - C)-A)$, $x \in ((C - B)-A)$, $x \in ((A\cap B)- (A \cap B \cap C))$,$x \in ((A\cap C)- (A \cap B \cap C))$, $x \in ((B\cap C)- (A \cap B \cap C))$, $x \in (A \cap B \cap C)$ which creates 7 different states for x and then by the rule of product is $7^n$ ways .

Comment: yeah, sorry my notation is not as precise, but you get the idea.